# Equation that produces negative one if x is less than zero and vice versa

Tags: education

I have tried coming up with something but i couldn't in the end...

basically i want something to produce -1 or 1. given value of x will not be equal to zero at any point. But if you want to add that, do so in another example. I'd like to have both, but need first one.

so

```
if x=2 
y=1
if x=-3435
y=-1
```

what i've tried:

well i thought i am gonna need  a way to make any number a one regardless of sign right.
so..

x-((x*-1)) working on it :D

can't use square root, absolute value(unless there is a equation for deriving absolute value).

Comment: i couldn't find tag suitable

Comment: would it be possible to do it without absolute value or is there a way to find absolute value using math only. No programming etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [sign function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function). Considering the restriction that $x \neq 0$, you could just write

$$\frac{x}{|x|}$$

Comment: check my comment thanks...

Comment: @MuhammadUmer What do you mean "find absolute value using math only"? The absolute value is defined mathematically just to be $|x| = x$ when $x \geq 0$, and $|x| = -x$ else.

Comment: i am trying to write a equation that can be run in a program that calculate this. i could use conditionals like you said, or use builtin methods. But i am wondering is it really not possible to derive absolute value without ifsss. (greater than zero then this etc..)

Comment: You could also use $|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$, but this will likely increase execution time if it's called a lot.

Comment: This does work perfectly fine, but it also sadly represented by a method in programming language.

Comment: i guess it's not possible to get absolute value without using square root.

Comment: Depending on whether your programming language has bitwise operations, you could use as the fastest method of absolute value (Four operations) the following: (Described in C) (y = x >> 31; x ^= y; x += y & 1;) (In words) (Store the value of arithmetically right-shifting your value (x) by 31 bits to a new variable, y. Store the xor of y and x to x. Store the sum of x and the bitwise and of y and 1 to x.

Comment: I dont get bitwise operators at all, would like to change that. But in meanwhile i'd rely on others. So yes, i have done that. Using bitwise operators in js you can find the absolute value like this: `(x^(x>>31))+((x>>31)&1)` no idea how it works. But it does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664852/which-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-the-absolute-value-of-a-number If you could explain that would be wonderful, and link that'd be ok as well. But thanks. :D

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It seems like you're going to a lot of effort to avoid a single case check, which is going to be very quick in terms of execution.

Comment: i agree, in js, i could just do this `(x>0)?1:-1;` which would just return 1 if number is big and -1 if negative.

Comment: check it out http://jsperf.com/absolute-value-bitwisevsifvsbit

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{|x|}{x}$ where $x \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like

if(x<0) y=-1; else y=+1?

With some appropriate way to handle x=0?

Comment: trying to squeeze performance if possible. But it all maybe pointless...:D

Comment: If all you want is the sign function, not the absolute value, an even faster way to do that would be sign(x) = (-2) * (x & 0x80000000) + 1, though this again relies on using bitwise and, and on being sure of the representation of your number.

Answer (score -1):

###### If you want $0$ or $1$:

$$ \frac { x + | x | } { 2 x } $$

So if $ x = - 7 $
$$ \frac { - 7 + \sqrt { ( - 7 ) ^ 2 } } { 2 ( - 7 ) } = 0 $$

If $ x = 7 $
$$ \frac { 7 + \sqrt { 7 ^ 2 } } { 2 \times 7 } = 1 $$

###### If you want $ - 1 $ and $ 1 $:

$$ \frac x { | x | } $$

If $ x = - 7 $
$$ \frac { - 7 } { \sqrt { ( - 7 ) ^ 2 } } = - 1 $$

If x = 7
$$ \frac 7 { \sqrt { 7 ^ 2 } } = 1 $$

###### For $ x < 0 $ to become $ 0 $ and $ x > 0 $ remain $ x $:

$$ \frac { x + | x | } { 2 } $$

If $ x = - 7 $
$$ \frac { - 7 + \sqrt { ( - 7 ) ^ 2 } } { 2 } = 0 $$

If $ x = 7 $

$$ \frac { 7 + \sqrt { 7 ^ 2 } } { 2 } = 7 $$

###### For $ x < 0 $ to remain $ x $ and $ x > 0 $ become $ 0 $:

If $ x = - 7 $
$$ \frac { - 7 + \sqrt { ( - 7 ) ^ 2 } } { 2 } - \sqrt { ( - 7 ) ^ 2 } = -7 $$

If $ x = 7 $
$$ \frac { 7 + \sqrt { ( 7 ) ^ 2 } } { 2 } - \sqrt { ( 7 ) ^ 2 } = 0 $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out :)